# Jquery to select a table row on click doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django, django-templates

I'm trying to toggle the class "highlight" of a html table row on click using JQuery. The table is created using Django template language. The table works and shows up in my development server and the Jquery works on tables not created with Django template language. I don't get any errors when running the code, but it just doesn't do anything when i click on a table row. I'm not sure what The problem could be.

**HTML**

```
<style media="screen">


 .highlight {
    background-color: yellow;
    color: white;
    }

</style>

<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table table-borderless" id="food_table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Price</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {% for order in orders %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{ order.pk }}</td>
        <td>{{ order.Price }}</td>
        <td>{{ order.Description }}</td>
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
$("#food_table tbody").on('click','tr',function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("highlight");
  });
```

**Dummy Data**

```
[
    {
        "pk": 9,
        "Description": "Pizza",
        "Price": "88.00"
    },
    {
        "pk": 10,
        "Description": "Steak",
        "Price": "130.50"
    },
    {
        "pk": 11,
        "Description": "Coca Cola",
        "Price": "25.95"
    },
    {
        "pk": 12,
        "Description": "Water",
        "Price": "15.00"
    }
]
```

Comment: Did you inspect the tr every time the click event is fired on the tr? tr's class should change - highlight class should toggle its presence/absence.

Comment: it is working check this https://jsfiddle.net/k9fLv31c/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to delegate it from the `body`

```
$("body").on('click','#food_table tbody tr',function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("highlight");
  });
```

Comment: or from `.table-responsive` perhaps

Comment: @Bell happy to help. Please consider upvoting and accepting it as answer

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it from body

```
$('body').on('click', '#food_table tbody tr', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('highlight');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you must try some like this . #food_table must be called with .click function jquery and you must import jquery resource in your html template

```
$("#food_table").click(function(){
     $(this).toggleClass('highlight');
   });
```

it's work for me fine .